# get image source path and set as background-image in a div container

Tags: jquery, css, html, background-image, blogger

I actually have no clue how to write a jQuery script so sorry in advance if what I try to attempt here is completely wrong.

I'm working on the home page of a blogger home page, where I want to showcase the first image as a thumbnail, which has a fixed 1:1 ratio and is responsive. 
I know that what I wish to end up with can be achieved by setting the CSS of the container with 
    `background: url(fistImageURL);
    background-size: cover;`
The problem is, that within an image Tag I can use `expr:src='data:i.firstImageUrl'` to get the source code, but I can't put `url(data:i.firstImageUrl)` in my CSS, so I try searching a jQuery solution for my problem...

I did try putting some stuff together I found around the Internet but I doesn't work, which actually doesn't really surprise me.

Anyway, it does look like this, so maybe you can understand what I try to achieve.

```
<script tpye="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.ar_content').css('background-image', 'url(document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src"))');
    });
</script>
```

Every solution is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**
This does actually do part of the job, but I'm still looking for something a little different.

```
<script tpye='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.ar_content').css('background-image', 'url('+document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src")+')');
    });
</script>
```

What this does is set the background of my div with the class `ar_content` to the very first image of the page, but what I need is to set the image within the container as the background image, so I suppose I should replace the `document` since I don't want to search the tags within the whole page, but only the content of the container.

And just to have it all, that's the Markup. The background-image should be the source of the image tag.

```
<div class='ar_content'>
    <a expr:href='data:i.url'><img class='img' expr:src='data:i.firstImageUrl'/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: providing relevant rendered HTML code would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution that works perfectly for my problem, just so this question get's an answer in case anyone else is facing the same thing.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.ar_content').find('img').each(function(n, image){
        var image = $(image);
        var thisurl = $(this).attr('src');
        image.parents('.ar_content').css('background-image', 'url(' + thisurl + ')');
      });
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution would have worked.

It's just the quotes like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.ar_content').css('background-image', 'url('+document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src")+')');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That does actually work with setting a background image, but it's always the same, which is my header image.

I have the image Tag within my .ar_content-Container and want this image set as a background. Do you know how that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the image src into the background like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.ar_content').css('background-image', 'url('+$("img:first")attr("src")+')');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i like to put some img's as background like this.

```
 $('.imgwrap').find('img').each(function(n, img) {
            img = $(img);
            var imgUrl = $(this).attr('src');
            img.parents('.imgwrap').css({
                'background': '#fff url(' + imgUrl + ') center center no-repeat',
                'background-size': 'cover',
                '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
                '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
                '-o-background-size': 'cover'
            });
            img.remove();
        });
```